# Vue Component In Shared Hosting

Tags: vue.js

How to make a change in the Vue component on shared hosting. I will change my Vue component and run npm command via ssh but changes not be display.

```
npm run prod
```

Comment: `npm run prod` runs Express web server. You are free to use your own web server with built app.

Comment: Can you explain? How can I do this?

Comment: You should build the bundle locally on your PC by `npm run build` and then simply upload the resulting `./dist` folder to your shared hosting.